# Converter arquivo com texto CSV

Tags: c++, arquivo, csv, binary

Estou com um trabalho em que preciso converter um texto de 200mil linhas de um arquivo csv para arquivo binário. Confiram um trecho do texto abaixo:

```
0,A Dijiang,M,24.0,180.0,80.0,China
1,A Lamusi,M,23.0,170.0,60.0,China
2,Gunnar Nielsen Aaby,M,24.0,170.0,60.0,Denmark
3,Edgar Lindenau Aabye,M,34.0,170.0,60.0,Denmark/Sweden
4,Christine Jacoba Aaftink,F,21.0,185.0,82.0,Netherlands
5,Christine Jacoba Aaftink,F,21.0,185.0,82.0,Netherlands
6,Christine Jacoba Aaftink,F,25.0,185.0,82.0,Netherlands
7,Christine Jacoba Aaftink,F,25.0,185.0,82.0,Netherlands
8,Christine Jacoba Aaftink,F,27.0,185.0,82.0,Netherlands
9,Christine Jacoba Aaftink,F,27.0,185.0,82.0,Netherlands
```

A informações seguem um padrão entre:

```
ID, nome do Atleta, sexo, idade, altura, peso, nacionalidade
```

Não sei mexer muito bem aqui no fórum ainda, no entanto, creio que meu código falta somente a criação da função inserir, que vai converter todo o texto para arquivo binário, mas não sei como cria lá, já que no arquivo binário o texto deve ser convertido seguindo essas separações por vírgulas.

```c
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
class campos
{
   private:
    int    id;
    string name;
    char   sex;
    float  age;
    float  height;
    float  weight;
    string team;
    int    elementos;

   public:
    campos();
    ~campos();
    void tratativa(string dados);
    void inserir();
    void listar();
};
campos::campos() { elementos = 0; }
campos::~campos() {}
void campos::tratativa(string dados)
{
    string       recebe = "";
    stringstream buffer;  // usa a biblioteca e ajuda a
                          // receber valores de varios tipos
                          // e ser capaz de converter eles.
                          // Idependente do tipo de dado
    for (int i = 0; i < dados.size(); i++)
    {
        if ((dados[i] != ',') && (dados[i + 1] != '\0'))
        {
            recebe += dados[i];
        }
        else
        {
            if (dados[i + 1] == '\0') recebe += dados[i];
            switch (elementos)
            {
                case 0:
                    buffer.str(recebe);
                    buffer >> id;
                    buffer.clear();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    name = recebe;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    buffer.str(recebe);
                    buffer >> sex;
                    buffer.clear();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    buffer.str(recebe);
                    buffer >> age;
                    buffer.clear();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    buffer.str(recebe);
                    buffer >> height;
                    buffer.clear();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    buffer.str(recebe);
                    buffer >> weight;
                    buffer.clear();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    team = recebe;
                    break;
                default:
                    elementos = 0;
                    break;
            }
            recebe = "";
            elementos++;
        }
        if (elementos > 6) elementos = 0;
    }
    inserir();
}
void campos::inserir()
{
    int tamName = name.size();
    int tamTeam = team.size();
}
void campos::listar()
{  // temporario -
    cout << "\ncampos:\n";
    cout << "id: " << id << endl;
    cout << "name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "sex: " << sex << endl;
    cout << "age: " << age << endl;
    cout << "height: " << height << endl;
    cout << "weight: " << weight << endl;
    cout << "team: " << team << endl << endl;
}
int main()
{
    ifstream arq("data_athlete_info.csv");
    string   linha, header;
    int      contLinha = 0;
    campos   c;
    if (arq)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {  // por enquanto e um for, mas deve mudar para um
           // while e a cada ciclo ele vai chamar
           // tratativa() e depois inserir no arquivo
            getline(arq, linha);
            if (contLinha == 0) { header = linha; }
            else
            {
                c.tratativa(linha);
                c.listar();
            }
            contLinha++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        arq.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seu programa tem muitos problemas e vai ter muito trabalho para concluir assim. Não use `void f(void)` é um desastre.  Escreva em torno dos dados: CSV é apenas texto: leia o texto, monte o registro e grave um a um. Devia ser uma classe

Comment: Para ler os dados considere que `scanf()` foi escrita para isso. Outro caminho bem comum é usar uma máquina de estados.

Answer (score 0):

Converter 2, 20 ou 200.000 linhas não faz assim muita diferença.

> > creio que meu código falta somente a criação da função inserir

Como o objetivo do código é ler os registros da entrada e gerar o tal arquivo binário com os dados, e seu código separa os campos, uma  parte do caminho foi percorrida. É um pouco frágil contar os campos de 7 em 7 e talvez uma máquina de estados fosse mais sólida do que um contador circular. E `stringstream` e strings talvez sejam *over*, algo demais para o problema aqui já que CSV é texto. E muito mais lento.

Entenda que `scanf()` foi escrita exatamente para isso: **scan f**ormatted input. E está disponível em `cstdio`. Então deve ser considerada quando a idéia é exatamente essa: CSV é entrada formatada.

Um arquivo CSV pode ser implementado na memória como `char ** **`  e é uma tabela `MxN` onde `M` é o total de registros e `N` o total de campos. E cada regsitro tem exatos `n-1` delimitadores (e talvez só isso). A primeira linha costuma ter o nome dos campos.

CSV está disponível para intercâmbio de dados em tudo, desde os gigantescos bancos de dados do Google Cloud aos programas de impressão de etiquetas de mala direta, passando por programas como bancos de dados , MS Excel e outras planilhas.

Quando é preciso um tratamento mais elaborado dos campos --- como em um programa de produção --- uma máquina de estados é em geral a opção, porque é mais flexível e fácil de testar e implementar.

### um exemplo de uma outra possível *"tratativa"*

### escrevendo em torno dos dados: uma classe `CSV_bin`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Registro.h"
using std::string;

class CSV_bin
{
   public:
    bool valido;
    string arq_csv;
    string arq_bin;

    CSV_bin(const char*, const char*);
    CSV_bin();
    ~CSV_bin();

   private:
     Registro um;
};
```

Essa classe hipotética permitiria escrever

```
#include "CSV_bin.h"
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    CSV_bin teste("arquivo.csv", "arquivo.bin");
    return 0;
}
```

e gerar `arquivo.bin` a partir de `arquivo.csv` e deixaria a vida mais fácil para tratar 1 ou um vetor desses arquivos. Esse é o caso do exemplo que vou deixar a seguir.

#### uma classe `Registro`

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
struct Registro
{
    unsigned ID;
    char     nome[80];
    char     sexo;
    float    idade;
    float    altura;
    float    peso;
    char     origem[80];

    int mostra()
    {
        std::cout << "\t[" << ID << ":\"" << nome
                  << "\""
                  << ", " << sexo
                  << ", Idade: " << idade
                  << ", Altura: " << altura
                  << " Peso: " << peso
                  << ", Origem: " << origem << " ]\n";
        return 0;
    }

    int grava(std::ofstream& out)
    {   // grava 'um' em 'out'
        if (not out.good()) return -1;
        out.write((const char*)this, sizeof(Registro));
        if (not out.good())
        {
            std::cerr << "Erro na saida. Verifique.\n";
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;  // ok
    }
};
```

Essa classe bem simples (e *header only* nesse caso) tem a descrição do registro e dois métodos triviais para mostrar um registro na tela e para gravar na saída.
Escrevendo assim permite usar encapsulamento e facilita mudar e testar essas coisas, tanto o formato de saída como o display, compilando apenas esse arquivo. C++ é para isso.

#### uma implementação de `CSV_bin`

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "CSV_bin.h"

CSV_bin::CSV_bin(const char* csv, const char* bin)
    : arq_csv(csv), arq_bin(bin), valido(false), um()
{
    auto          N       = 0;
    const char*   mascara = "%d,%[^,],%c,%f,%f,%f,%s";
    std::string   linha{};
    std::ifstream f_csv{csv};
    std::ofstream f_bin;
    f_bin.open(bin, std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
    if (not f_bin.good()) return; // algo saiu errado na criacao
    while (f_csv.good())
    {
        N += 1;
        std::getline(f_csv, linha);
        std::cout << "leu:\t\"" << linha << "\"\t[" << N
                  << "]\n";
        memset((void*) &um, 0, sizeof(Registro));
        int nc = sscanf(
            linha.c_str(), mascara, &um.ID, &um.nome,
            &um.sexo, &um.idade, &um.altura, &um.peso,
            &um.origem);
        if (nc != 7) // nao leu os 7 campos ...
        {   std::cerr << "Erro na entrada. Verifique a "
                "ultima linha\n";
            break;
        }
        um.mostra(); // so para conferir
        if ( um.grava(f_bin) != 0)
        {  
            std::cerr << "Erro na saida. Verifique.\n";
            break;
        }
    };  // while()
    std::cout << "\nlidas " << N << " linhas de " << csv
              << "\ngravados " << f_bin.tellp()
              << " bytes em " << bin << "\n";
    f_csv.close();
    f_bin.close();
    valido = true;
}

CSV_bin::CSV_bin() : CSV_bin("entrada.csv", "saida.bin") {}
CSV_bin::~CSV_bin(){};
```

Essa é uma implementação simples de `insere()` do código original mas nesse contexto é apenas o construtor da classe. O construtor padrão assume nomes para os arquivos d eentrada e saída. Claro que apenas para teste os registros são mostrados na tela usando a classe `Registro`. E os argumentos deveriam vir na linha de comando.

#### saida do programa usando o arquivo de exemplo

```
leu:    "0,A Dijiang,M,24.0,180.0,80.0,China"   [1]
        [0:"A Dijiang", M, Idade: 24, Altura: 180 Peso: 80, Origem: China ]
leu:    "1,A Lamusi,M,23.0,170.0,60.0,China"    [2]
        [1:"A Lamusi", M, Idade: 23, Altura: 170 Peso: 60, Origem: China ]
leu:    "2,Gunnar Nielsen Aaby,M,24.0,170.0,60.0,Denmark"       [3]
        [2:"Gunnar Nielsen Aaby", M, Idade: 24, Altura: 170 Peso: 60, Origem: Denmark ]
leu:    "3,Edgar Lindenau Aabye,M,34.0,170.0,60.0,Denmark/Sweden"       [4]
        [3:"Edgar Lindenau Aabye", M, Idade: 34, Altura: 170 Peso: 60, Origem: Denmark/Sweden ]
leu:    "4,Christine Jacoba Aaftink,F,21.0,185.0,82.0,Netherlands"      [5]
        [4:"Christine Jacoba Aaftink", F, Idade: 21, Altura: 185 Peso: 82, Origem: Netherlands ]
leu:    "5,Christine Jacoba Aaftink,F,21.0,185.0,82.0,Netherlands"      [6]
        [5:"Christine Jacoba Aaftink", F, Idade: 21, Altura: 185 Peso: 82, Origem: Netherlands ]
leu:    "6,Christine Jacoba Aaftink,F,25.0,185.0,82.0,Netherlands"      [7]
        [6:"Christine Jacoba Aaftink", F, Idade: 25, Altura: 185 Peso: 82, Origem: Netherlands ]
leu:    "7,Christine Jacoba Aaftink,F,25.0,185.0,82.0,Netherlands"      [8]
        [7:"Christine Jacoba Aaftink", F, Idade: 25, Altura: 185 Peso: 82, Origem: Netherlands ]
leu:    "8,Christine Jacoba Aaftink,F,27.0,185.0,82.0,Netherlands"      [9]
        [8:"Christine Jacoba Aaftink", F, Idade: 27, Altura: 185 Peso: 82, Origem: Netherlands ]
leu:    "9,Christine Jacoba Aaftink,F,27.0,185.0,82.0,Netherlands"      [10]
        [9:"Christine Jacoba Aaftink", F, Idade: 27, Altura: 185 Peso: 82, Origem: Netherlands ]

lidas 10 linhas de entrada.csv
gravados 1800 bytes em saida.bin
```

#### como testar? usando a classe `Registro`

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Registro.h"
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    const char*   arquivo = "saida.bin";
    auto          N       = 0;
    Registro      um;
    std::ifstream f_bin;
    f_bin.open( arquivo, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
    if (not f_bin.good()) return 0;  // algo saiu errado na criacao
    f_bin.read((char*)&um, sizeof(Registro));
    while (f_bin.good())
    {
        N += 1;
        um.mostra();
        f_bin.read((char*)&um, sizeof(Registro));
    };  // while()
    std::cout << "\n\n\t" << N
              << " registros lidos do arquivo binario \""
              << arquivo << "\"\n";
    f_bin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Esse programa simples abre o arquivo gerado e mostra o conteúdo na tela

#### listando o arquivo binário

```
        [0:"A Dijiang", M, Idade: 24, Altura: 180 Peso: 80, Origem: China ]
        [1:"A Lamusi", M, Idade: 23, Altura: 170 Peso: 60, Origem: China ]
        [2:"Gunnar Nielsen Aaby", M, Idade: 24, Altura: 170 Peso: 60, Origem: Denmark ]
        [3:"Edgar Lindenau Aabye", M, Idade: 34, Altura: 170 Peso: 60, Origem: Denmark/Sweden ]
        [4:"Christine Jacoba Aaftink", F, Idade: 21, Altura: 185 Peso: 82, Origem: Netherlands ]
        [5:"Christine Jacoba Aaftink", F, Idade: 21, Altura: 185 Peso: 82, Origem: Netherlands ]
        [6:"Christine Jacoba Aaftink", F, Idade: 25, Altura: 185 Peso: 82, Origem: Netherlands ]
        [7:"Christine Jacoba Aaftink", F, Idade: 25, Altura: 185 Peso: 82, Origem: Netherlands ]
        [8:"Christine Jacoba Aaftink", F, Idade: 27, Altura: 185 Peso: 82, Origem: Netherlands ]
        [9:"Christine Jacoba Aaftink", F, Idade: 27, Altura: 185 Peso: 82, Origem: Netherlands ]


        10 registros lidos do arquivo binario "saida.bin"
```

#### Sobre o arquivo binário

Esse exemplo é só um brinquedo e considera os campos de nome e origem como tendo o tamanho fixo de 80 bytes. E assim o arquivo pode ser lido usando `seek` e `tell` e navegando pelos registros como em um grande array.
O formato csv provavelmente é melhor do que as possíveis implementações de arquivos binários em quase todos os casos.
De todo modo uma coisa comum a considerar seria usar registros de tamanho variável para todos os campos de tamanho variável na saída, usando um campo inicial com o tamanho do buffer e campos descrevendo o tamanho de cada campo interno, como nas strings em Pascal.
Não vou escrever o exemplo mas é também trivial.
Note que o CSV tem um overhead de apenas 7bytes por registro --- e mais algo que se poderia ganhar gravando ID em binário e talvez com os campos float --- e assim náo deve compensar mexer nisso em um programa real, portabilidade a parte.

#### Compilando o exemplo

Para rodar isso basta copiar e colar `Registro.h` `CSV_bin.h` `CSV_bin.cpp` e `main.cpp` como estão acima

Comment: Então essa resposta, que tem uma discussão do problema e inclui um programa completo em C++ com uma possível implementação, um programa de teste e um programa para validar o resultado, é inútil? Talvez os ilustres anônimos que consideraram essa resposta inútil pudessem me ajudar a melhorar o nível do que escrevi :D